# Random Variable measurable on two $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Suppose $X$ is a random variable defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal G, \mathbb P)$ with $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $\mathcal G = \{\phi,\Omega, \{1,3,5\}, \{2,4,6\}\}$. Then $X$ could look like this.

$$X(\omega) = \begin{cases} 1 \mbox{ if }\omega \in \{1,3,5\},  \quad \\ 0 \mbox{ if }\omega \in \{2,4,6\} \end{cases}  $$

My perhaps very silly question is, what does $X$ look like on $\mathcal F= \mathcal {P}(\Omega)$. I know that if $X$ is $\mathcal G$ measurable, then $X$ should also be $\mathcal F$ measurable, but I cannot figure out how to write it out explicitly without ending up with a random variable that's not $\mathcal G$ measurable.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question. $X$ is a function from $\Omega \to \{0,1\}$. In particular, there is no notion of measurability here, so changing the $\sigma$-field does not change the definition of $X$.

Comment: @AndrewZhang I am trying to show that a sigma algebra $\mathcal A$ is not a subset of another sigma algebra $\mathcal B$ by showing that an $\mathcal A$ measurable random variable $X$ is not $\mathcal B$ measurable. So I'm trying to build a function such that the Borel sets inverse under $X$ are not in $\mathcal B$ but are in $\mathcal A$. As such, I need an explicit function, so I tried getting an idea from this example, clearly not working haha! I guess I will edit the question to further clarify if this comment doesn't do the trick